# Creating a computed value to calculate the cost doesn't work

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfmiranda75/L8Zhj/) with an example. I have some profiles and a cost per hour, and I'm trying to make the sum, but it only works the first time. If I modify some of the values, the sum doesn't update.

I have this function to calculate the sum:

```
self.valoracion = function () {
    var total = 0;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.perfilesValorados(), function (item) {
        var tarifa = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.perfiles(), function(perfil) {
            return perfil.perfil === item.perfil;
        });
        total += parseInt(item.horas) * tarifa.tarifa;
    });
    return total.toFixed(2);
};
```

But if I change it to make it computed, I have an error saying that perfilesValorados is not a function.

How could I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to make 2 changes in your code:

1. Change your `valoracion` to be [computed function](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html). Why? because you want the sum value to be recalculated whenever any of your `observable` value is changed.
2. In order for step(1) to work your `perfiles` array objects that you calculate `valoracion` to hold `observable` properties (*and here comes the problem trick*).

For step 2 you already defined `Profile` model with `observable` properties but when added objects to `perfiles` array you didn't use it (***I must wonder why?***). To fix this you can simply add an `init` to your ViewModel in which you construct your `perfiles` array correctly. I hope you got the idea.

***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L8Zhj/5/)***

***Update:***

For your updated example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jfmiranda75/nsR9W/) which is not working, your problem in inserting new element to `observableArray` you have.

According to [Observable Arrays documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html):
*The syntax is more convenient. To call KO’s push method, just write `myObservableArray.push(...)`*

So update your code in init function to use:

1. `self.perfiles.push` instead of `self.perfiles().push`
2. `self.perfilesValorados.push` instead of `self.perfilesValorados().push`

Working version of your updated example ***[here](http://jsfiddle.net/nsR9W/4/)***

Comment: Thanks for your help. I receive all data from an asp.net mvc action in json format, and thought that when I assign the values like perfiles(data.perfiles), this array would be populated with their values. I also made another example, but allowing to change the hours, but I have the same problem. This is the fiddle: jsfiddle.net/jfmiranda75/nsR9W